# Rows from MySQL table is only getting displayed in console and not in POSTMAN?

Tags: mysql, node.js, serverless, serverless-framework, mysql2

I'm using MySQL, Nodejs and Serverless-offline plugin here.

For some reason the results from MySQL table are only being displayed in the console of VSCode and not in POSTMAN. What should I do to get the results on screen(hope you understood what I meant) instead of console?

Here, is code:

In `db.js`:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const db = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  port: 3307,
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "nodejs_beers",
});

db.connect((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
    return;
  }
  console.log("database connected");
});

module.exports = db;
```

In `serverless.yml` file:

```
plugins:
  - serverless-offline

functions:
  read:
    handler: ./handlers/handler.getUsers
    events:
      - http:
          method: get
          path: /getUsers
          responseType: 'text/plain'
```

In `handler.js`:

```
const db = require('../db/db')
const mysql = require('mysql2')
const email = require('../email')
const stringify = require("json-stringify-safe");


module.exports.getUsers = async (event) => {
    try {
      // SELECT query to get all details from "beers" table
      console.log("outside users");
      const result = await db.query("SELECT * FROM beers");
      console.log("outside users 1");
      console.log({result});
      return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: stringify({ message: "Query executed successfully", data: result }),
      };
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return {
        statusCode: 500,
        body: stringify({ message: "An error occurred", error: error.message }),
      };
    }
  };
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Done. Please Check now

Comment: Are you sure you're meant to be returning an object with `statusCode` and `body` properties? The examples I'm seeing from a quick search just return whatever data they want

Comment: I did those because when I was returning the results, I was getting error:502. So, I just tried it this way. Its fine even if statuscode and body are not returned.

Comment: @Phil I did those because when I was returning the results, I was getting error:502. So, I just tried it this way. Its fine even if statuscode and body are not returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing the `responseType` configuration from the serverless yml file as you are returning a json response.

Also try with `JSON.stringify()` your response before going with "json-stringify-safe" to confirm whether the issue is related to the dependency.